# C library - use in C++: redefinition, different type modifiers

Tags: c++, typedef, redefinition

I recently built a CSV library in pure C. 
The header file looks as follows:

```
  #ifndef CSV_H
  #define CSV_H

    #include "unicode/ustdio.h"
    #include "unicode/uchar.h"
    #include "unicode/ucsdet.h"
    #include "unicode/ustring.h"

    #define T CSV_T
    typedef struct T *T;

    extern T    CSV_new(char *filename);
    extern void CSV_free(T *csv);
    extern int  CSV_length(T csv);
    extern void CSV_print_info(T csv);
    extern UChar **CSV_get_header(T csv);
    extern UChar ***CSV_get_values(T csv);
    extern long CSV_get_num_columns(T csv);
    extern long CSV_get_num_lines(T csv);
    extern char *CSV_get_charset(T csv);

    #undef T
    #endif
```

The actual definition of the struct CSV_T is done in the code file, to hide the implementation. I used the library quite often in different projects using pure C, no problem. Now I wanted to re-use the code in a GUI application that is built with C++, and I get the following error message:

```
Error   C2373   'CSV_T': redefinition; different type modifiers     ... xxx\Projects\LibCSV\LibCSV\csv.h    10
```

Does C++ handle something about typedefs different than C? Confusing somehow,...

Comment: Post your [MCVE], not this "..." nonsense

Comment: Also a bit of critique - you should use `const char*`, and why would you take over the single-letter `T` using a macro just to replace the already-short `CSV_T`? That's really bad.

Comment: `typedef struct T *T` is not a good idea for C++ code.

Comment: Here you go.
Agree on `const char *`. The definition is just for consistency among different libraries. Bad, ok, but I got used to it and I guess it doesn't hurt the compiler,...:-)

Comment: @n.m. could you elaborate why that is?

Comment: The line that immediately succeeds the posted error message in your error report should be rather illuminating, showing you where the prior version is, and what the difference actually is. Why you didn't include it in your question remains a mystery. "it doesn't hurt the compiler" - clearly the C++ compiler disagrees with that view.

Comment: @WhozCraig: You are mistaken. That one line is all that is required.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm *not* mistaken. the rest of the error report will show that, indeed, it is the same line, certainly, but the actual messaging would explain *why*, as *your* posted answer demonstrates.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, not in this particular case, with `typedef struct T *T;` being so blatantly wrong. But in the general case, the OP should follow WhozCraig's advice.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Advice to add more code to the question, when in fact the OP should be _removing_ code, is certainly not correct.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, It wasn't advice to add more code, but to add more of the error log. It seems you have a misunderstanding.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Ah, you meant the next error. lol sorry

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes, the "note: previous declaration here" - exactly. ( +1 on the answer, btw)

Comment: @WhozCraig: In my defence it's still morning

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit in mine, it's 3:20am and I should have gone to bed hours ago =P

Comment: Nah, the next error line does not tell where there has been another definition:
`"test" uses undefined struct 'CSV_T'`
So yes, it seems that `typedef struct CSV_T *CSV_T` is no good idea in C++.

Comment: @inzanez: _"but I got used to it and I guess it doesn't hurt the compiler,"_ It'll hurt the compiler extremely. You say it's for consistency with other libraries? That's unlikely. `T` is so short and generic that it is almost guaranteed to give you a massive conflict headache.

Comment: It's not a good idea in `C` either. Just please don't

Comment: @StoryTeller: In C, the typedef is perfectly legal.
If it's good style or not can be argued...

Comment: Just because it's legal to shoot yourself in the foot, doesn't make it a good idea. Don't obfuscate your code like this. Use separate identifiers for the struct and the pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c222a5ff0462d8c)'s what your MCVE should look like:

```
typedef struct T *T;
```

This is a complete, one-line source file that reproduces the issue and has no dependencies. No macros, no headers, no unnecessary code.

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp:1:19: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct T* T'
 typedef struct T *T;
                   ^
main.cpp:1:16: note: previous declaration as 'struct T'
 typedef struct T *T;
            ^
```

The reason it works in C is that `T` was not already the name of a struct; you needed the `struct` prefix.

In C++, this is not true, because the `struct` prefix wasn't required in the first place. As soon as you have declared that `T` is a class (which, confusingly, you did in the `typedef` itself!), you can't just give some other type (the one you're trying to create with the `typedef`) the same name.

It's rather bizarre what you're doing anyway, making `CSV_T` mean `struct CSV_T*`. I suggest simply not doing this.

If you were simply sticking with a `typedef struct CSV_T CSV_T` then this would work in both languages, but trying to make a *different* type with the same name just isn't going to work.

Comment: Ok, so there's the difference. I'll go over the source again then,...many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Appendix C to the C++ standard says:

> 7.1.3
>
> **Change:** A C++ typedef name must be different from any class type name declared in the same scope (except if the typedef is a synonym of the class name with the same name). In C, a typedef name and a struct tag name declared in the same scope can have the same name (because they have different name spaces).
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> typedef struct name1 { /.../ } name1; // valid C and C++
> struct name { /.../ };
> typedef int name; // valid C, invalid C++
> ```
>
> **Rationale:** For ease of use, C++ doesn’t require that a type name be prefixed with the keywords class, struct or union when used in object declarations or type casts.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>  class name { /.../ };
>  name i; // i has type class name
> ```
>
> **Effect on original feature:** Deletion of semantically well-defined feature.
>
> **Difficulty of converting:** Semantic transformation. One of the 2 types has to be renamed.
>
> **How widely used:** Seldom.